# Grouping mysql results by multiple key value pairs

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a db table that stores multiple 'tags' for a client.

| client_code | tag_key | tag_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | price | high |
| ABC | size | big |
| XYZ | price | high |
| XYZ | size | small |

I need to filter for clients by particular tags.

This is easy if I am searching for one type of tag. For example, all clients that have a high price point:

`SELECT DISTINCT(client_code) FROM tb_client_tags WHERE (tag_key  = 'price' AND tag_value = 'high')`

How would I do this for multiple key value pairs?
For example, if I wanted to search by price and size.

The following works, but it seems quite inefficient!

```
SELECT client_code FROM 
(
    SELECT client_code, SUM(C) AS total FROM 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT(client_code), 1 AS C FROM tb_client_tags WHERE (tag_key = 'pricepoint' AND tag_value = 'medium')
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DISTINCT(client_code), 1 AS C FROM tb_client_tags WHERE (tag_key = 'client_size' AND tag_value = 'large')
    ) T
    GROUP BY client_code
) T_1
WHERE total = 2;
```

Any tips would be most appreciated!

Comment: If there are more than 2 distinct tag_keys then the sample data is misleading. if there are only 2 distinct tag_keys you should say so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search clients that match either of the condition (`WHERE`) and then choose those that match all of them (`HAVING`):

```
SELECT client_code
FROM tb_client_tags
WHERE 
  (tag_key='price' and tag_value='high') or 
  (tag_key='size' and tag_value='big')
GROUP BY client_code
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag_key)=2
```

Btw, in your sample code `DISTINCT` is not a function. It affects all columns.

Comment: `.. WHERE (tag_key, tag_value) IN ( ('price', 'high'), ('size' , 'big' ) ) ..` seems to be more clear..

Comment: Great, thanks - much easier that way!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to filter by two key-value pairs only then

```
SELECT client_code
FROM tb_client_tags t1
JOIN tb_client_tags t2 USING (client_code)
WHERE (t1.tag_key, t1.tag_value) = ('price', 'high')
  AND (t2.tag_key, t2.tag_value) = ('size' , 'big' )
```

if you need to filter by 2-3-4-more key-value pairs then use generic technique provided in [@slaakso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1052130/slaakso)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76572461/10138734).